# How to find the equation of tangent plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Find the equation of the tangent plane to the surface given by following equation, at $R(u,v)$ at the point $(2,2,3)$
$$\vec R(u,v)=u\hat i+2v^2\hat j+(u^2+v)\hat k$$

My attempt:
$$\frac{\partial \vec R}{\partial u}=(1, 0, 2u), \ \frac{\partial \vec R}{\partial v}=(0, 4v, 1), $$
The normal vector to the surface $\vec R $ is
$$\vec n=\frac{\partial \vec R}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial \vec R}{\partial v}=(-8uv, -1,4v)\tag 1$$
Now, I satisfy the equation of $\vec R=(u, 2v^2, u^2+v)$ by $(2,2,3)$ which gives me
$u=2, v=-1$
now, I plugged in these values of $u$ and $v$ to find normal vector
$\vec n=(16, -1, -4)$

the equation of plane: $(\vec r-\vec a)\perp \vec n$
$$(\vec r-\vec a)\cdot \vec n=0\quad $$
$$(x-2,y-2,z-3)\cdot (16,-1, -4)=0$$
$$16x-y-4z-18=0$$
could someone tell if I am wrong or right. please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks alright to me

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. Here it is another way. We have that
$$\begin{cases}
x=u\\
y=2v^2\\
z=u^2+v=x^2+v
\end{cases}\implies 2(z-x^2)^2=y.$$
Then the given surface is the level set $F(x,y,z)=0$ where $F(x,y,z)=2(z-x^2)^2-y$.
Hence, for any $(x,y,z)$ such that $F(x,y,z)=0$, we have
$$\vec n=\nabla F(x,y,z)=(-8(z-x^2)x,-1,4(z-x^2))$$
and at $(2,2,3)$ we find
$$\vec n=\nabla F(2,2,3)=(-8(3-4)2,-1,4(3-4))=(16,-1,-4).$$
Then the equation of the tangent plane follows in the same way.